# Draw every pixel in canvas

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, canvas

I have two-dimensional array with size equal screen resolution `int[][] matrix = new int[width][height]` where `width` and `height` are size of screen. I modify array after some multitouch events on screen, for example increase or decrease value of each item. I need to draw in realtime each item in array to each pixel in canvas. For example if value of item is higher then pixel is darker.

I try to use [Android draw using SurfaceView and Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956583/) as base. In thread class in override function run in loop throw every array item I do like this `canvas.drawPoint(w, h, paint)`. But it is not quick.

Am i right to do this? What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not completely wrong, you do not have to redraw every pixel each frame, so you should definitely somehow store the changed pixels and draw **only** them each render loop run.